# How to change a colour reflection/glow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I replaced the shirt on this stock image, from a green one to a red one. As you can see the glow of the green shirt on the boys chin.

[image]

Is there a way to target only that area and make it red (in photoshop)?

(Masking the area and doing it that way is producing a bad result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose a small, soft edged brush. Set the brush colour mode to "Color" in the tool options along the top.

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and sample some of the skin colour with the Eyedropper tool.

Paint over the image.

[image]

Here's the before and after for comparison

[image]

If you think the effect is a little strong, undo it, and bring down the brush opacity a little, and repeat.

Comment: Below his chin still has a greenish tinge, I like Scott's usage of Hues.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on @BillyKerr's answer... I think the **Hue** blend mode is more appropriate. And brush over the *entire* face, not merely the chin.

Set the Brush tool blend mode to **Hue** and sample a rosey color from a cheek. Then paint over the entire face and neck.

There are subtle green highlights in the neck, cheeks, ears, nose, even forehead. Using Hue retains all the values and saturation and merely alters the value for the actual hue being referenced, changing it from the green to a rosey color.

[image]

Click the image to see it larger.

This is the *same technique* Billy describes, merely with a slight change. He deserves all the credit. I was going to simply post this as a comment, but feared it may get lost or go unseen.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, hower, this image is part of a larger composition, so this will be about 200 pixel square. So I don't need so much detail. However the green glow was a bit obvious, hence my dilemma.

Comment: No problem @AasimAzam :)  I would point out how much "warmer" the overall image is even at a small size by eliminating *all* the green tints, not just those on the chin. You can see, what appears to me, to be a pretty stark difference in my image above.

Comment: I must say i agree with scott here, the cheek is also greenish so just doing the skin makes it look a bit off. @AasimAzam